property .registerHealthIndicator(true) in Resilience4J CircuitBreaker is unavailable
I am trying to configure Resilience4J CircuitBreaker in my Kotlin Springboot application. This is a Springboot2 application.
My current Resilience4J version is 1.7.0. But when I try to set the .registerHealthIndicator(true), it is not available in the current version. I upgraded to 2.2.0, but I still have an error. I want to see CircuitBreaker's status in actuator/health. How can I see the CircuiteBreaker status without this setting?
Additionally, I am a bit confused with what is the difference between spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j jar vs resilience4j-spring-boot3jar.
 @Bean
fun circuitBreaker(): CircuitBreaker {
    val config = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
        .registerHealthIndicator(true) // Error - Unresolved reference: registerHealthIndicator
        .recordExceptions(SocketTimeoutException::class.java) 
        .slidingWindowSize(5) 
        .minimumNumberOfCalls(3)
        .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
        .automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled(true)
        .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(50))
        .failureRateThreshold(50f)
        .build()
    return CircuitBreaker.of("myCircuitBreaker2", config)
}

I have added below config in my application.yml.
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true

But still the /health shows as {"status":"UP","components":{"circuitBreakers":{"status":"UNKNOWN"}, ..."
